# Saving Word File as a Picture Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word

I'd like to save the first page of a Word document as a picture.  What methods are there for doing this with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the word document to an XPS document, open it in a WPF (.Net 3.5) app and convert the first internal FixedPage object to a bitmap using the document and imaging functionality of the WPF framework. The XPS document printer is available if you have the .Net 3 framework installed (maybe 3.5, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the Word file to PDF (using one of the freely available converters), or print to Postscript (Windows printer driver). Then convert PDF or PS to an image, using e.g. ImageMagick's *convert* command or ghostscript.

http://www.imagemagick.org/

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

Comment: How can I do it programatically? How can I embed the converters?