# Rendering the first page of a word document as an image in both .NET and Java

Tags: java, .net, ms-word

We're working on a content management system where we need to dynamically show the first page of a word document as a thumbnail. What could be the process to do this using both Java and .NET.

Comment: Similar to the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833880/saving-word-file-as-a-picture-programmatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384116/convert-msword-first-page-to-image. Might help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java side, you could use something based on OpenOffice since it has an API and can automatically generate the thumbnail.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) is on option which exposes the thumbnail (`TemplateDetails.getThumbnail()`), [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) may also be able to help.